# JavaScript - print the element value

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
<div onclick="updateElementWithValue()" id="element">Value 1</div>
<div onclick="updateElementWithValue()" id="element">Value 2</div>
<div onclick="updateElementWithValue()" id="element">Value 3</div>
```

JS:

```
updateElementWithValue(){
//need to add some code here to make the function work!
alert('This is element : ');
}
```

what I want to do, is for example if I click on :

```
<div onclick="updateElementWithValue()" id="element">Value 2</div>
```

It displays the value of that div, in the above case, it should show : **Value 2**

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use the same ID for multiply elements: `id="element"`

Comment: @andlrc I have a for loop that prints the same element ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: don't use the same id for multiple elements.

Second: give the element as parameter:  `updateElementWidthValue(this)`.

The function is:

```
function updateElementWithValue(element) { 
    alert('This is element: ' + element.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: You might tell a little about `node.addEventListener('click', ...);`

Comment: this will always get value1 because he is putting the same id for the DOM element